# How to avoid issue with unguaranteed useCallback deps in useEffect deps?

Tags: react-hooks

I have recently started to use the new React Hooks API and I find it awesome!

However, I ran into a small confusion in the dependencies area.

## What is this about?

Basically, my use case is pretty simple, and can be illustrated by the following pseudo code:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'

function Component() {
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  const doStuff = useCallback(() => {
    // Do something 
    setState(result)
  }, [setState])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Do stuff ONLY at mount time
    doStuff()
  }, [])

  return <ExpensivePureComponent doStuff={doStuff} />
}
```

Now, the above code works fine.

But after I installed `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, there is a warning. I must declare all dependencies that is use in my effects, which is, here, `doStuff`.

Fine, let's fix that code:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // Do stuff ONLY at mount time
    doStuff()
  }, [doStuff])
```

**Cool, no more warning!**

## Wait, no warning, but... no bug either?

Let's see what the docs say about `useCallback`:

> useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)

And then, about `useMemo`:

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee**. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render

So, basically, my `doStuff` callback, hence my `useEffect`, isn't guaranteed anymore to only run at mount time? Isn't that a problem?

I understand the principles behind the eslint plugin, but it looks to me that there is a dangerous confusion between `useCalback`/ `useMemo` dependencies arrays, and `useEffect` one's, or am I missing something?

It might be, because even the docs say that my final code is fine:

> If for some reason you can’t move a function inside an effect, there are a few more options:
>
> ● ...
>
> ● As a last resort, you can add a function to effect dependencies but wrap its definition into the useCallback Hook. **This ensures it doesn’t change on every render unless its own dependencies also change**

---

## me: blah blah hooks bla

## SO: What is your question? :)

Well, what do you think? Code is safe? Docs say it is, but also say it is not, because callback is not guaranteed to not change... this is a bit confusing.

Is there a bad practice in the above pseudo code? When that pattern cannot be avoided, what to do? `// eslint-disable-next-line`?

Answer (score 2):

While the docs say that

```
useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)
```

it doesn't mean that useCallback is implement using `useMemo` and it certainly is not. So while useMemo may choose to calculate again useCallback won't update the function unless the something in dependency array changes.

Also since the setter returned by `useState` doesn't change, you don't need to pass it on to the `useCallback`

```
  const doStuff = useCallback(() => {
    // Do something 
    setState(result)
  }, [])
```

Since doStuff won't change, `useEffect` won't be called again apart from initial mount.

One thing however that you should keep in mind while using `useEffect` and `useCallback` is that if you dependency array in useCallback changes the callback will be recreated and hence useEffect will re-rerun. One way to prevent such scenarios is to make use of `useReducer` hook instead of `useState` and rely on `dispatch` to update state since it won't ever change during the course of your App interactions in a session.

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'

const initialState = [];
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_STATE' : {
            return action.payload
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}
function Component() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);


  useEffect(() => {
    // Do stuff ONLY at mount time
    dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_RESULT', payload: ['xyz']})
  }, [])

  return <ExpensivePureComponent dispatch={dispatch} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the alternative you propose! While I agree that `useCallback` is not *implemented upon* `useMemo`, they use the exact same code under the hood...

Comment: Like all first order hooks actually (based on `mountWorkInProgressHook()` and `updateWorkInProgressHook()` - https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L994). Maybe it will be a core feature that will detect "expensive" data holding and free memory based on that, not based on which type of hook that uses it? In that case memoized functions should be fine indeed... (but I would be interested to hear the actual plan :))

Comment: Thanks for addressing "if dependency array in useCallback changes the callback will be recreated and hence useEffect will re-rerun" that was causing a loop.